# In SQL Server, I need to pack 2 characters into 1 character, similar to HEX. How?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, packed-decimal, comp-3

I have a SQL Server table that has a column in it that is defined as Binary(7).
It is updated with data from a Cobol program that has Comp-3 data (packed decimal).
I wrote a C# program to take a number and create the Comp-3 value. I have it available to SQL Server via CLR Integration. I'm able to access it like a stored procedure.

My problem is, I need to take the value from this program and save it in the binary column. When I select a row of data that is already in there, I am seeing a value like the following:

0x00012F0000000F

The value shown is COBOL comp-3 (packed decimal) data, stored in the SQL table. Remember, this field is defined as Binary(7). There are two values concatenated and stored here. Unsigned value 12, and unsigned value 0.

I need to concatenate 0x00012F (length of 3 characters) and 0x0000000F (length of 4 characters) together and write it to the column.

My question is two part.

1) I am able to return a string representation of the Comp-3 value from my program. But, I'm not sure if this is the format I need to return to make this work. What format should I return to SQL, so it can be used correctly?

2) What do I need to do to convert this to make it work?

I hope I was clear enough. It's a lot to digest...Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms: I hope you were clear enough ;-)

Comment: @TaW: it is enough for OP to make their own research :-)

Comment: @Steve:  _I am able to return a string representation of the Comp-3 value from my program._ How does this look?

Comment: Why would you do this in SQL? Just store the number as a normal integer or decimal and handle the conversions in the C# code as necessary.

Comment: I have to do it this way because it is a 3rd party software that is written in Cobol that writes to a SQL Server database. We need to work with the database to insert records from other systems to use in this system. I have not other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!
I needed to change the output to byte[], and reference it coming out of the program in SQL as varbinary.

This is the code, if anyone else in the future needs it. I hope this helps others that need to create Comp-3 (packed decimal) in SQL. I'll outline the steps to use it below.

Below is the source for the C# program. Compile it as a dll.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace Numeric2Comp3
{
//PackedDecimal conversions

public class PackedDecimal
{

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void ToComp3(string numberin, out byte[] hexarray, out string hexvalue)
    {

        long value;
        bool result = Int64.TryParse(numberin, out value);

        if (!result)
        {
            hexarray = null;
            hexvalue = null;
            return;
        }

        Stack<byte> comp3 = new Stack<byte>(10);

        byte currentByte;
        if (value < 0)
        {
            currentByte = 0x0d;     //signed -
            value = -value;
        }
        else if (numberin.Trim().StartsWith("+"))
        {
            currentByte = 0x0c;     //signed +
        }
        else
        {
            currentByte = 0x0f;     //unsigned 
        }

        bool byteComplete = false;
        while (value != 0)
        {
            if (byteComplete)
                currentByte = (byte)(value % 10);
            else
                currentByte |= (byte)((value % 10) << 4);
            value /= 10;
            byteComplete = !byteComplete;
            if (byteComplete)
                comp3.Push(currentByte);
        }
        if (!byteComplete)
            comp3.Push(currentByte);
        hexarray = comp3.ToArray();
        hexvalue = bytesToHex(comp3.ToArray());
    }

    private static string bytesToHex(byte[] buf)
    {
        string HexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder((buf.Length / 2) * 5 + 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
        {
            sbyte b = Convert.ToSByte(buf[i]);
            b = (sbyte)(b >> 4);     // Hit to bottom
            b = (sbyte)(b & 0x0F);   // get HI byte
            sb.Append(HexChars[b]);
            b = Convert.ToSByte(buf[i]);             // refresh
            b = (sbyte)(b & 0x0F);   // get LOW byte
            sb.Append(HexChars[b]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    } 

} 
}
```

Save the dll somewhere in a folder on the SQL Server machine. I used 'C:\NTA\Libraries\Numeric2Comp3.dll'.

Next, you'll need to enable CLR Integration on SQL Server. Read about it on Microsoft's website here: [Introduction to SQL Server CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Open SQL Server Management Studio and execute the following to enable CLR Integration:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Once that is done, execute the following in Management Studio:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY Numeric2Comp3 from 'C:\NTA\Libraries\Numeric2Comp3.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

You can execute the following to remove the assembly, if you need to for any reason:

```
drop assembly Numeric2Comp3
```

Next, in Management studio, execute the following to create the stored procedure to reference the dll:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Numeric2Comp3
@numberin nchar(27), @hexarray varbinary(27) OUTPUT, @hexstring nchar(27) OUTPUT
AS
EXTERNAL NAME Numeric2Comp3.[Numeric2Comp3.PackedDecimal].ToComp3
```

If everything above runs successfully, you're done!

Here is some SQL to test it out:

```
DECLARE @in nchar(27), @hexstring nchar(27), @hexarray varbinary(27)
set @in = '20120123'
EXEC Numeric2Comp3 @in, @hexarray out, @hexstring out

select len(@hexarray), @hexarray

select len(@hexstring), @hexstring
```

This will return the following values:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
5                   0x020120123F

(No column name)    (No column name)
10                  020120123F
```

In my case, what I need is the value coming out of @hexarray. This will be written to the Binary column in my table.

I hope this helps others that may need it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Comp-3 stored in a binary filed as a hex string, well I wonder if the process that created this is working as it should.

Be that as it may, the best solution would be to cast them in the select; the cast sytax is simple, but I don't know if a comp-3 cast is available.

Here are examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188362.aspx).

So let's work with the string: To transform the string you use this:

```
string in2 = "020120123C";
long iOut = Convert.ToInt64(in2.Substring(0, in2.Length - 1)) 
          * (in2.Substring(in2.Length - 1, 1)=="D"? -1 : 1 ) ;
```

It treats the last character as th sign, with 'D' being the one negative sign.  Both 'F' and 'C' would be positive.

Will you also need to write the data back?

I am curious: What string representaion comes out for fractional numbers like 123.45 ?

( I'll leave the original answer for reference..:)

---

Here are a few lines of code to show how you can work with bit and bytes.

The operations to use are:

- shift the data n bits right or left: `<< n` or `>> n`
- masking/clearing unwanted high bits: e.g. set all to 0 except the last 4 bits:  `& 0xF`
- adding bitwise: `|`

If you have a string representation like the one you have shown the out3 and out4 byte would be the result. The other conversions are just examples how to process bit; you can't possibly have decimals as binarys or binarys that look like decimals. Maybe you get integers - then out7 and out8 would be the results.

To combine two bytes into one integer look at the last calculation!

```
// 3 possible inputs:
long input = 0x00012F0000071F;
long input2 = 3143;
string inputS = "0x00012F0000071F";

// take binary input as such
byte out1 = (byte)((input >> 4) & 0xFFFFFF );
byte out2 = (byte)(input >> 36);

// take string as decimals
byte out3 = Convert.ToByte(inputS.Substring(5, 2));
byte out4 = Convert.ToByte(inputS.Substring(13, 2));

// take binary as decimal
byte out5 = (byte)(10 * ((input >> 40) & 0xF) + (byte)((input >> 36) & 0xF));
byte out6 = (byte)(10 * ((input >> 8) & 0xF) + (byte)((input >> 4) & 0xF));

// take integer and pick out 3rd and last byte 
byte out7 = (byte)(input2 >> 8);
byte out8 = (byte)(input2 & 0xFF);

// combine two bytes to one integer
int byte1and2 = (byte)(12) << 8 | (byte)(71) ;

Console.WriteLine(out1.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out2.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out3.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out4.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out5.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out6.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out7.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(out8.ToString());    
Console.WriteLine(byte2.ToString());
```

Comment: The input is a regular integer value, such as 100, or a decimal value such as 123.45.

Comment: _a decimal value such as 123.45_ How shall the fractional part be treated?

Comment: The input is a regular integer value, such as 100, or a decimal value such as 123.45. I'm getting the correct value coming out, I'm just not sure what data type it needs to be coming out of the program. Right now, it's coming out as string, but that's not correct. 
For example, I have 20120123 going in, and 020120123C coming out. The length of this output value is 10 because it's a string. The length needs to be 5 for the same value, just like a regular hex number. Run the following in SQL ( select len(0x123F), len('0x123F') ) and you will see the first value is 2, and the second is 6.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I figured it out. See my reply below.